# Using $.inArray("str", arr) considering elements which contains that str

Tags: jquery

I have this array: `var arr = ["hi","heya","hello"]` and I need to find whatever element which contains "hey", being that element not necessarily "hey" exactly, so "heya" counts.

So I need something like this:

```
var arr = ["hi","heya","hello"];
if($.inArray("hey",arr) != -1) alert("hey found!");
```

which shows nothing, but I need it to.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In loop indexOf does the trick.

```
var arr = ["hi","heya","hello"];
var found = false;
$.each(arr, function(index, value){        
      if (value.indexOf("hey") !== -1){
            found = true;
            return false;
      }      
});
if(found){
alert('hey found');
}
else{
alert('hey not found');
}
```

[**Working Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ru7ge/42/)

Comment: why is necessary to use "return false"? I've commented that line and works too. Is this a good practice or something to optimice the code?

Comment: Let's say your array is huge and match is found at 3rd index then why will you iterate rest of the items,moreover it's like a break statement while the item is found.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a regular expression for this, and making use of the `grep` function apply the test to each element of the array

```js
var arr = ["hi","heya","hello"];
var search = new RegExp("hey" , "i");
var array = $.grep(arr, function (value) {
    return search.test(value);
});

/* Array Contains Elements Like */
if(array.length==0) console.log("Not Found");
else{ 
    console.log("found!");
    console.log(array);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search the word by lopping.The following code will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
    var arr = ["hi","heya","hello"];
    $.each(arr, function( index, value ) {
        var data = value.search('hey');
        if (data === 0) {
            alert(value);
        }
    });
});
```